# Drawing line between Wikipedia and Skeptics.SE

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to deal with questions which an off-site search can answer?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-to-deal-with-questions-which-an-off-site-search-can-answer)

From this question I came to know [Wikipedia is a valid reference](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289/is-wikipedia-a-valid-reference) here. Although personally I did not research for any answer to any question belonging to the site, I do have a bad feeling that some of the questions posted here, can be answered using simple [Google search](http://www.google.com) or Wikipedia search.
e.g The [answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5202/has-the-catholic-church-ever-retracted-an-ex-cathedra-statement) to the question holds direct citing from four different links out of which three are directly from Wikipedia. I believe if the asker had done serious researches, he could answer his own question.

Or to this [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/12472/does-passive-smoking-kill-600-000-people-every-year), in the answer a single link is given that is enough for the answer.

I believe maximum of the answerers are not living Encyclopedia themselves. They also search the web, maybe the difference is they search the web for more time that the asker. Even the answers sometimes hold just gist of information from different sources.
Now the basic requirement of asking question in SE sites is doing research before asking. But I fear if serious research is done for the questions, Skeptics might loose its significance due to lack of questions.

**So what is the real significance of Skeptics.SE given the fact maximum facts can easily be searched and found in Wikipedia?**

NB: Its just a clarification questions, users please don't nurture hard feelings!

Comment: In general, Wikipedia is not a valid reference, and that question says so, even though it's not clear. Our current policy is that Wikipedia should be treated as a reference for definition and high school level claims only.

Comment: @Sklivvz, What do you mean by _high school level claims_?

Comment: Meaning that Wikipedia is enough evidence to support simple, uncontested statements. If you want to provide evidence that the mass of the moon is so-and-so kilograms, you can use Wikipedia and you don't need to find the original sources. For anything more complex, you need to look at primary sources or meta studies.